# GCP Cloundrun overwrites response header character

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

So I setup the rail api app in cloudrun and this api server is supposed to return custom http response header in UPPERCASE.
However when I deploy on Cloudrun of GCP, it gives you response in LOWERCASE.

Does anyone know why and how to solve this problem?

I'm aware for HTTP/2, it's expected to return http header key in LOWERCASE but this cloudrun is not configured for HTTP/2.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to change your code to be case insensitive.

RFC 7230 (HTTP/1.1) Section 3.2: `Each header field consists of a case-insensitive field name followed by a colon (":"), optional leading whitespace, the field value, and optional trailing whitespace.`

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2

For years, the convention has been to go to lowercase only. I still see a lot of first letter capitalized as in `Content-Length`, but `content-length` should be used. However, your code should not be performing case-sensitive comparisons as that violates the RFCs.

**[UPDATE 2/17/2021]**

I just noticed today that the Java HttpServer class also converts response headers. If you attempt to return `CONTENT-TYPE`, the library will change it to "Content-type". The reason for my additional comment is to show that Google is not the only vendor that changes the character case of HTTP response headers.

Comment: Ohh...looks like I have to change the code then....Thank you for your response!